# How to change Default alert sound in iCal?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, notifications

I would like to change the default sound ("basso") that plays when an Alert is fired from iCal in the notification center?

I have tried changing the sounds in notification center, but it seems to be overridden by the iCal settings. Can the sound be changed to "glass" or any other?

One way, I can do it is by changing the Alert sound when I create a Calendar Event. This is just too cumbersome to do everytime.

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a alternative way to do that.

Go to System/Library/Sounds and create a sound file with the same name as Basso.aiff and it will supersede Basso without the need for deleting a system sound file.

Answer (score 0):

**I hate the basso sound.** I prefer not to have any sound on my alerts, except on rare occasions.

I went to the command line and did 'touch Basso.aiff'. That creates a zero kb file that you can copy to /System/Library/Sounds/

I do wish however, that there were a way to set the alarm default to "no sound". That would be the correct way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make a .aiff file containing silence

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though it does answer part of it.